# Airflow DAG Run triggered, but never executed?

Tags: airflow

I've found myself in a situation where I manually trigger a DAG Run (via `airflow trigger_dag datablocks_dag`) run, and the Dag Run shows up in the interface, but it then stays "Running" forever without actually doing anything.

When I inspect this DAG Run in the UI, I see the following:

[image]

I've got `start_date` set to `datetime(2016, 1, 1)`, and `schedule_interval` set to `@once`. *My* understanding from reading the docs is that since `start_date` < now, the DAG will be triggered. The `@once` makes sure it only happens a single time.

My log file says:

```
[2017-07-11 21:32:05,359] {jobs.py:343} DagFileProcessor0 INFO - Started process (PID=21217) to work on /home/alex/Desktop/datablocks/tests/.airflow/dags/datablocks_dag.py
[2017-07-11 21:32:05,359] {jobs.py:534} DagFileProcessor0 ERROR - Cannot use more than 1 thread when using sqlite. Setting max_threads to 1
[2017-07-11 21:32:05,365] {jobs.py:1525} DagFileProcessor0 INFO - Processing file /home/alex/Desktop/datablocks/tests/.airflow/dags/datablocks_dag.py for tasks to queue
[2017-07-11 21:32:05,365] {models.py:176} DagFileProcessor0 INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/alex/Desktop/datablocks/tests/.airflow/dags/datablocks_dag.py
[2017-07-11 21:32:05,703] {models.py:2048} DagFileProcessor0 WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(BashOperator): foo>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2017-07-11 21:32:05,703] {models.py:2048} DagFileProcessor0 WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(BashOperator): foo2>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2017-07-11 21:32:05,704] {jobs.py:1539} DagFileProcessor0 INFO - DAG(s) dict_keys(['example_branch_dop_operator_v3', 'latest_only', 'tutorial', 'example_http_operator', 'example_python_operator', 'example_bash_operator', 'example_branch_operator', 'example_trigger_target_dag', 'example_short_circuit_operator', 'example_passing_params_via_test_command', 'test_utils', 'example_subdag_operator', 'example_subdag_operator.section-1', 'example_subdag_operator.section-2', 'example_skip_dag', 'example_xcom', 'example_trigger_controller_dag', 'latest_only_with_trigger', 'datablocks_dag']) retrieved from /home/alex/Desktop/datablocks/tests/.airflow/dags/datablocks_dag.py
[2017-07-11 21:32:07,083] {models.py:3529} DagFileProcessor0 INFO - Creating ORM DAG for datablocks_dag
[2017-07-11 21:32:07,234] {models.py:331} DagFileProcessor0 INFO - Finding 'running' jobs without a recent heartbeat
[2017-07-11 21:32:07,234] {models.py:337} DagFileProcessor0 INFO - Failing jobs without heartbeat after 2017-07-11 21:27:07.234388
[2017-07-11 21:32:07,240] {jobs.py:351} DagFileProcessor0 INFO - Processing /home/alex/Desktop/datablocks/tests/.airflow/dags/datablocks_dag.py took 1.881 seconds
```

What could be causing the issue?

Am I misunderstanding how `start_date` operates?

Or are the worrisome-seeming `schedule_interval` `WARNING` lines in the log file possibly the source of the problem?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that the dag is paused.

In the screenshot you have provided, in the top left corner, flip this to `On` and that should do it.

This is a common "gotcha" when starting out with airflow.

Comment: Hmm. I am running `airflow unpause datablocks_dag`, followed by `airflow trigger_dag datablocks_dag`. Am I running them in the wrong order, perhaps?

Comment: That should work fine in theory. However, in the UI we can see the dag is still paused. Not sure why... Unpausing it manually should work.

Comment: I have gone ahead and reversed the order of the calls, and it now works as expected.

Comment: Wow. Wow.   Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is correct. This issue can be handled through UI.

One other way of handling this is by using configuration.

By defualt all dags are paused on creation. 
You can check the default configuration in `airflow.cfg`

```
# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True
```

Turning the flag on will start your dag after the next heartbeat.

Relevant git [issue](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin/issues/8#issuecomment-299569391)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it had to with depends_on_past or wait_for_downstream